# REVISTED$^2$: Fraction Existence Proof

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, fractions

### Question 1:

I'm asked to prove that there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\frac{a}{b}<\frac{1}{n},$$
where $0<\frac{a}{b}<1$. Here $\frac{a}{b}$ is a fraction in lowest terms.

---

### Q1(Thoughts):

If $\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\frac{a}{b}<\frac{1}{n},$ then with a bit of algebra we get that
$$0\leq\frac{an^2-bn+a}{b}<1,$$
so since $0<\frac{a}{b}<1$ we can set $an^2-bn+a=a$ to get that $an^2-bn=0$, which produces
$$n=\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4a\cdot 0}}{2a}=\frac{b\pm b}{2a},$$
and since $n\neq 0$, then we get that $n=\frac{b}{a}$.

OK, so that was totally wrong, but I've got that $\frac{a}{b}\in[\frac{1}{2},1)\implies n=1,$ $\frac{a}{b}\in[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2})\implies n=2$, and so on *ad infinitum*, but I don't know that this is a proof. It looks as though no matter what $\frac{a}{b}\in\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$.

---

### Question 2:

If $n$ is chosen as in Q1, prove that $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ is a fraction that in lowest terms has a numerator less than $a$.

---

### Q2(Thoughts):

I think this might have something to do with $n<\frac{b}{a}$.

---

I'll be adding more to this as I go, but my question is essentially something like "Is this right?"

Comment: As $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{1}{n}$ and $n = \frac{b}{a}$, $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a}{b}$ which is false. So your argument is incorrect.

Comment: I just caught that too, as I later found out that it's supposed to be an $n$ such that $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{n+1}$, where in lowest terms the numerator is less than $a$, but in my example it would be $a^2$, which is false.

Comment: I think you went wrong when you said "we can set $an^2 - bn + a = a$" because $a$ is a fixed given value, so you need to choose a different variable for the right hand side.

Comment: I've posted an answer that I think is simpler than both the one proposed in the question and the one mentioning the Archimedean property.  There's really no need to mention Archimedean properties.

Answer (score 7):

There's a problem with your proof, since you conclude that $n = \frac b a$, which is not guaranteed to be an integer. Furthermore, as Michael pointed out, the conclusion that $n = \frac b a$ leads to $\frac a b < \frac a b$, which is problematic.

Regardless, there's actually an easier way to proceed, using the Archimedian property. Let $\alpha = \frac a b$, so that $\frac 1 \alpha > 1$. Let $n$ be the greatest natural number less than $\alpha$, so that $n + 1 \ge \alpha$. What can you conclude from here?

Comment: . . . . . and there's an easier way to proceed than any argument citing an Archimedean property.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set
$$
\left(\frac12,1\right] \cup \left(\frac13,\frac12\right] \cup \left(\frac14,\frac13\right] \cup \left(\frac15,\frac14\right] \cup \cdots \cup\left(\frac1{b+1},\frac1b\right]
$$
This set certainly contains $\dfrac1b,\dfrac2b,\dfrac3b,\ldots,\dfrac{b-1}b$.  One of those is $\dfrac ab$.

Comment: Yeah... That's what I have here on paper... See my notes above. Should I write $\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}(\frac{1}{1+n},\frac{1}{n}]$ instead?

Comment: Shouldn't your union be infinite?

Comment: It doesn't need to be infinite.  You've given us a fration $a/b$, whose numerator and denominator are finite.  For each such fraction, we need to look only at finitely many intervals of the sort above.  For example, if $b=17$, we don't need to look beyond $(1/18,\  1/17]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: . . . . and I would add that going into an infinite union complicates the proof unnecessarily.  One shouldn't make a proof look more complicated than it really is. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: ... and my name is Michael Hardy